# Hide overflow only when page size is too low

Tags: html, css, image, overflow, wrapper

I've a div named page with lets say `1000px width` and `position: relative;` and in this page div I've a logo with `position: absolute;` and `top:-20px; right: -20px`. When the page width is more than 1000px the image should be displayed but when the page width is equal or lower than 1000px the overflow should be hidden (`overflow: hidden;`).

When I set the overflow attribute in the page div to `overflow: hidden;` the logo is cropped and when I choose `visible` I get a horizontal scroll bar when the page width is equal or lower than 1000px.

My idea to solve this issue is to use JavaScript and set the `overflow` attribute depending on the page width. I would prefer a CSS solution but couldn't find one. :-/

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this using CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple...

Just make a wrapper div around the page. Let's say the page div is 1000px width and the wrapper div has `width: 100%`. Then it's the easiest way to set `overflow: hidden`for the wrapper div and when the page size shrinks to for example 1020px a piece of the image is cropped and when the size shrinks further to 1000px the horizontal scrollbar appears because of the page div (which has the default `overflow: visible`).

And that's it... works in (almost) every 5 year old browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media queries (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to change the layout based on screen size. i.e.:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
#page { overflow: hidden; } 
}

#page { overflow: visible; }
```

Comment: This sounds very good but does this work on older browsers (IE7, 8?)?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with CSS ( Not Javascript for browser layout issues )  - and use an @media query.

Like this, where the place you want the horizontal scroll to appear is 1200px and below.

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) { 
html {overflow-x: hidden;}

Stick that at the end of your style sheet, or in some  tags in your header to test.